# Failed with error 1117 after 1 attempts taking 3 ms

Tags: mongodb

I am not able to start mongo db. when I try to see the starting log it shows me an errer as - Failed with error 1117 after 1 attempts taking 3ms.

> 2019-05-16T11:29:35.204+0530 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover final skipped jo
>   urnal section had sequence number 795336061
>   2019-05-16T11:29:35.204+0530 I JOURNAL  [initandlisten] recover applying initial
>   journal section with sequence number 795498722
>   2019-05-16T11:29:35.209+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] FlushViewOfFile for C:/P
>   rojects/ccknia/mongo-database/data/db/soliprotection.2 failed with error 1117 af
>   ter 1 attempts taking 3ms
>   2019-05-16T11:29:35.209+0530 I -        [initandlisten] Fatal Assertion 16387
>   2019-05-16T11:29:35.896+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
>   ngo\util\stacktrace_win.cpp(175)             mongo::printStackTrace+0x43
>   2019-05-16T11:29:35.897+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
>   ngo\util\log.cpp(134)                        mongo::logContext+0x97
>   2019-05-16T11:29:35.897+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
>   ngo\util\assert_util.cpp(166)                mongo::fassertFailed+0x80
>   2019-05-16T11:29:35.899+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
>   ngo\util\mmap_win.cpp(488)                   mongo::WindowsFlushable::flush+0x5b
>   b
>   2019-05-16T11:29:35.900+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
>   ngo\util\mmap.cpp(204)                       mongo::MongoFile::_flushAll+0x21d
>   2019-05-16T11:29:35.901+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
>   ngo\db\storage\mmap_v1\dur_recover.cpp(582)  mongo::dur::RecoveryJob::go+0x300
>   2019-05-16T11:29:35.902+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
>   ngo\db\storage\mmap_v1\dur_recover.cpp(617)  mongo::dur::_recover+0x1d3
>   2019-05-16T11:29:35.903+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
>   ngo\db\storage\mmap_v1\dur_recover.cpp(631)  mongo::dur::replayJournalFilesAtSta
>   rtup+0x62
>   2019-05-16T11:29:35.904+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo
>   ngo\db\storage\mmap_v1\dur.cpp(883)          mongo::dur::startup+0x36
>   2019-05-16T11:29:35.905+0530 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] mongod.exe    ...\src\mo

Comment: is this a new installation or existing database?

Comment: its existing database - suddenly there was a shutdown in server - now not able to start mongodb

Comment: What version is this? Are you still using MMAPv1?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have a backup of the data folder and then try to execute the following:

`mongod --repair --repairpath <data path>`